Is shifting 0 to the left considered undefined behavior in C?
Is either of these expressions Undefined Behavior (UB)?

0 << 32
0LL << 64

I would appreciate it if the answer includes references to the C standard.

Why on earth would this be undefined?

I just want to be sure. Frankly, I wouldn't be surprised, given that the C standard indeed surprises me sometimes. For example, when it states that 1 << 31 is undefined behavior.

I assume, you are talking about a system where 32 and 64 bits are the sizes of int and long long int. For a language lawyer question you should add that to the question.

Do you mean 0 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof 0) and 0LL << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof 0LL)?

@Gerhardh In the real world, only two mainstream implementations of int exist: 16 bit or 32 bit. This is UB in either case. Only one mainstream implementation of long long exists: 64 bits. Also UB. Anyone interested in exotic or fictional computers can perhaps take that discussion elsewhere, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or some such.

@Lundin practically of course you are right. But aren't posts here that are tagged "language-lawyer" require a bit higher level of "strictness" (this applies to answers as well) ? I actually avoided to post an answer here because I was not sure I can adhere to that "strictness".

@wohlstad Addressing exotic/fictional systems in an answer just distracts from what the question is actually about. There is not a single sane person in the world who cares about how 0 << 32 is handled on a fictional system with 8 byte int.

@Lundin I agree that systems with 8 byte int are probably not very interesting. But what about a system where int is 64 bit ? On such system 0 << 32 would not be UB. Although I admit I didn't encounter such a system yet ...  I am really not trying to waste anybody's time, just want to establish this issue better from the C standard point of view.

@Lundin: When the question is tagged language-lawyer, it is about the rules of the language, not about what you assert people care about.

@EricPostpischil And so we have in the past for example suffered endless debates about useless crap such as signed magnitude and one's complement. Now these are suddenly gone from C because nobody used them. As history now shows, all those debates about signedness of fictional computers were 100% useless waste of space all along, to no use to any living human, but distracting plenty from what actually needed to be communicated - the behavior of 2's complement.

@Lundin: When the question is tagged language-lawyer, it is about the rules of the language, regardless of your opinion of the value of the question or the answers.

Refer to ISO/IEC 9899:201x Programming languages -- C, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators, paragraph 3:

The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Assuming the common configuration of 32-bit int and 64-bit long long:
Analyze 0 << 32 expression: the right operand is the integer constant 32, the value is equal to the width of the left operand (int). So the behavior is undefined.
Analyze 0LL << 64 expression: the right operand is the integer constant 64, the value is also equal to the width of the left operand (long long). So the behavior is also undefined.
Both 0 << 32 and 0LL << 64 result in undefined behavior (UB) in C.

This answer is both completely correct and completely wrong: these expressions do have undefined behavior, but only because of the paragraph immediately preceding the one that this answer quotes.

@wohlstad I don't think it works that way. If one paragraph says, it is undefined, then another paragraph that is addressing some other condition, can not void that statement. I would say, it is undefined if any of these paragraphs tells us so. Not if both do. Edit: I saw that the answer initially mentioned the same paragraph as yours.

@wohlstad you are right. The question should clearly state that the shown numbers represent the sizes of involved types. But on the other hand.... If that wasn't the case, the question would be completely pointless anyway.

@lollol The answer is correct now after the edit. The value of the left operand doesn't matter in this case because the right operand is causing the UB. It is UB regardless of left or right shift as well.

Removed my previous comments. They referred to the original answer before it was edited.

This answer assumes a machine with 32 bit int objects and 64 bit long long objects. It's also UB on machines with smaller int and long long objects (for the same reason). It's not UB on a machine with larger types, but I doubt any such machine exists.

@ikegami long long cannot be smaller than 64 bits. (63 value bits + 1 sign bit)

@SheltonLiu,  "the right operand is the integer constant 32, the value is equal to the width of the left operand (int)." deserves improvement as an int is not certainly 32-bit.  It may be as low as 16-bit or even, uncommonly, even wider.  It is sufficient to assume it is 32 to explain things, yet that assumptions deserves being stated.

@chux noted that!

@ikegami There's DSPs with support for 36-bit or 40-bit integers. For example, TMS320C553 series DSPs have a 40-bit ALU, 17-bit multiplier and both 16-bit and 32-bit data buses. Incidentally, it has defined shifts for number of bits from -32 to 31. So what size is an int? Who knows!

@chux See p.14 of AMD64 Architecture Processor, int type uses 4 bytes = 32-bit object and  long long type uses 8 bytes = 64-bit object.

@SheltonLiu "int type uses 4 bytes = 32-bit object " is an implementation specification.  int may be as narrow as 16-bit and with no specified upper bound.  See a C spec.  OP did request "I would appreciate it if the answer includes -references to the C standard.".  16-bit int is fairly common in embedded processors in 2024.  Some graphic processors are known to use 64-bit int.
